# conhost.exe process duplication in Visual Studio | can't close conhost

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, console, taskmanager

I have a windows forms project and it several forms each one had a button to close the one form and open another by doing that code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Menu MenuForm = new Menu();
    MenuForm.Show(); // Shows main menu
    this.Hide();
 }
```

When I switched between forms it duplicated consoles on the background and i can't close it.

[image: process is marked red]

I tried debug=>stop debugging and manually killing process in task manager.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSoD7.png)

all consoles consume such memory in my pc, they seem to automatically run as i open VS